# Unable to pass array data from view to controller using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

The data (array of array) is not getting passed from view to controller while using AJAX in CodeIgniter (PHP)

url is working in $.ajax. It is redirecting to the method in controller

view.php (view)

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var table_data = [];

    // use .each to get all data
    $('#data_table tr').each(function(row,tr){

        // create array again to store data by row
        // get only data with value 

        if ($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text() == "") {
        } else {
        var sub = {
            'no' : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            'firstname' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            'middle' : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            'last' : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
        };

        table_data.push(sub);
    }
});

//use ajax to insert the data

console.log(table_data); 

var data = {'data_table':table_data};

console.log(data);

 $.ajax({
    data : data,
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'save',
    crossOrigin : false,
    dataType : 'array',
    success: function(msg){
        $('.answer').html(msg);
     }

});
```

Welcome.php (controller)

```
public function save() {

    $relatives_list = $this->input->post('data'); 
    echo 'as';

    echo $relatives_list; 
    // the list is not shown here

    $this->load->model('Batch');
    $status = $this->Batch->save($relatives_list);

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('status' => $status)); 
}
```

Batch.php (model)

```
 public function save($relative_list){
$length = count($relative_list);

    for($x = 0; $x < count($relative_list); $x++){
        $data[] = array(
            'no' => $relative_list[$x]['no'],
            'firstname' => $relative_list[$x]['firstname'],
            'middle' => $relative_list[$x]['middle'],
            'last' => $relative_list[$x]['last'],

        );
    }
    try {


        for($x = 0; $x<count($relative_list); $x++){
            $this->db->insert('hhh',$data[$x]);
        }
        return 'success';
    }catch(Exception $e) {
         return 'failed';
    }

}
```

Error:

> parameter-must-be-an-array-or-an-object-that-implements-countable

Comment: You override `$data` in the Batch.php first loop - I think you meant `$data[] = array(...`

Comment: Thanks! but the data is not getting passed from view to controller. 

In welcome.php below echo 'as' there is echo $relatives_list. The data is not shown in console.

Answer (score 1):

According to your script it wouldn't be `data` it would be `data_table`

```
var data = {'data_table':table_data};
```

Thus:

```
var_dump($this->input->post('data_table')
```

If that doesn't work please post the `console.log` of your `data` var.

Please note: you will have to remove the `echos` before `json_encode` after you are done troubleshooting or jquery will fail to parse the response.

Comment: Thanks for the input, now the array from ajax is passing from view to controller.

Comment: I'm getting a model error now

<p>Severity: Warning</p>

<p>Message:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable</p>

<p>Filename: models/Batch.php</p>

<p>Line Number: 6</p>

Comment: what is the result of the var_dump?

Comment: var_dump is working! Now echo $relatives_list in controller is working. But the data is now moving to Model. 
'Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable' is the error.

Comment: *data not moving to model

Comment: ok, and that error is pretty self explanatory with a quick google. hence why i wanted the result of `$relatives_list` so i can see why it is occurring. if you can provide that i can help.

Comment: Use unserialsize() besore send data to your model.

Comment: @Alex 
relatives_list result // Array 
(
    [no] => 1
    [firstname] => erw
    [middle] => sda
    [last] => fds
)
Array
(
    [no] => 2
    [firstname] => RAH
    [middle] => SYD
    [last] => REH
)

Comment: please, a `var_dump`

Comment: @Alex used var_dump but the data is passing as a string and not an array!